# Datalog code not working in DrRacket

Tags: prolog, scheme, racket, datalog

I am trying to run this prolog code in DrRacket: http://www.anselm.edu/homepage/mmalita/culpro/graf1.html

```
#lang datalog

arc(a,b).
arc(b,c).
arc(a,c).
arc(a,d).
arc(b,e).
arc(e,f).
arc(b,f).
arc(f,g).   

pathall(X,X,[]).
pathall(X,Y,[X,Z|L]):- arc(X,Z),pathall(Z,Y,L).       % error on this line; 

pathall(a,g)?
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
read: expected a `]' to close `['
```

I suspect '|' symbol is not being read as head-tail separator of the list. Additionally, `[]` is also giving error (if subsequent line is removed):

```
#%app: missing procedure expression;
 probably originally (), which is an illegal empty application in: (#%app)
```

How can these be corrected so that the code works and searches for paths between a and g ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Datalog module in DrRacket is not an implementation of Prolog, and the syntax that you have used is not allowed (see the [manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/datalog/datalog.html?q=datalog) for the syntax allowed).

In particular terms cannot be data structures like lists ([]). To run a program like that of above you need a Prolog interpreter with data structures.

What you can do is define for instance a predicate `path`, like in the example that you have linked:

```
path(X,Y):- arc(X,Y).
path(X,Y):- arc(X,Z),path(Z,Y).
```

and, for instance, ask if a path exists or not, as in:

```
path(a,g)?
```

or print all the paths to a certain node with

```
path(X,g)?
```

etc.

Comment: How can above  code  be  changed to properly working datalog code?

Comment: It can't, since a term cannot be a list. The Datalog Module in DrRacket is a very simple module not equivalent to Prolog, in particular it does not implements data structures. What you can do is only the first part of the example that you have linked, that is testing if a path exists or not, or print paths.

Comment: Is there  a way to use proper Prolog alongside Racket?

Comment: Not real Prolog, I think. Prolog is a language based on a programming paradigm completely different from that of Scheme/Racket, and to use proper Prolog you need a specific interpreter (that could be written in Scheme, of course). If you want to use Prolog you could start with  [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org), for instance, which is a free and powerful implementation.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, congratulations on reaching 10K reputation.

Comment: What? You totally can make a `#lang prolog`, it's just that `#lang datalog` is not it. @mso, out of curiosity, have you tried miniKanren?

Comment: I have seen it but have not tried it. How does it fare when compared with prolog and datalog?